# Make DynamicUpdate work with session.update

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Been able to successfully use wnwrap session to reduce SQL count to UPDATE only from SELECT + UPDATE for `Entity` (annotated with `@DynamicUpdate`) but DynamicUpdate is not working in that case.

```
doInJPA(entityManager -> {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
    for ( Post post: posts ) {
        session.update( post );
    }
});
```

Found `@DynamicUpdate` only works when using `entityManager.merge` pattern while doing update but it leads to 2 SQL queries while detached state SELECT + UPDATE.

```
doInJPA(entityManager -> {
    for ( Post post: posts ) {
        entityManager.merge( post );
    }
});
```

Can session unwrap pattern be made to do use of SQL UPDATE query generated by entityManager.merge , so that don't have to re-implement DynamicUpdate ?

`Note` -

1. Entity has `@Id` key on `String` dataType which is `UUID.toString` field and is not a generated field
2. tried implementing `Persistable` and `Transient` `isNew` and `getId` without success (i.e unable to reduce SELECT + UPDATE in case of `entityManager.merge` pattern to UPDATE only)
3. Been able to do insert successfully using single INSERT using `entityManager.createNativeQuery.executeUpdate` pattern, just the update is firing double queries with merge pattern. Session unwrap and update reduces it to 1 UPDATE but DynamicUpdate does not work
4. Tried Transactional at higher scope too so that GET + UPDATE are in same transaction without success

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic update will only work on managed entities(which requires an entity to be SELECTed at least once) because Hibernate relies on comparing state against snapshots which are created when doing a SELECT.

If you want real dynamic updates, I can recommend you take a look at [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which supports that: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#updatable-entity-views